# Having trouble allowing only one argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, arguments

I am a beginner at Bash scripting and my script is not behavioring properly. I do not know how to fix it or the proper way to code it. The user should only be able to enter one argument. (`$ nowOn f132a99`) If you enter more then one argument, then it will prompt the `Please enter a single, valid user id: "` I am not sure how to fix this.

$ nowOn f132a99 = Correct output

$ nowOn f132a99 f132a98 = Error on Line 1 Binary Operator Expected

$ nowOn f132a99 f132a98 f132a97 = Error on Line 1 Too Many Arguments

```
if [ -z "$@" ]; then
    echo -n "Please enter a single, valid user id: "
    read userid
else
    userid="$@"
fi

#user validation check
if ! grep -q "$userid" /etc/passwd >/dev/null 2>&1;then
        echo
        echo "The user you entered, $userid is not a valid user on this system."
        exit 2
else
        #login check
         if ! who | grep "$userid" >/dev/null 2>&1;then
                echo
                echo `grep "$userid" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5 | sort | sed 's/^\(.*\), \(.*\)$/\2 \1/'` is NOT currently logged on
                exit 1
else
        #login check
        echo
        echo `grep "$userid" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5 | sort | sed 's/^\(.*\), \(.*\)$/\2 \1/'` is currently logged on.
        exit 0
        fi
fi
```

I have also tried the following code down below but if you enter more then one argument (`nowOn f132a99 f132a97`) then it will just display the results for f132a99 and disregard the rest, and not echo `Please enter a single, valid user id:`

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo -n "Please enter a single, valid user id: "
    read userid
else
    userid="$1"
fi
```

Comment: You have a lot of problems than just validating user input.

Comment: For the requirement of the assignment, the code works and does what it needs to do. What problems do I have?

Comment: Notice that your "redacted" stuff is still available in the history,  see it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/579323/1).

Comment: I rolled your edit back. The question is useless without code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your test `[ -z "$@" ]` does not work as you expect it to do.  The `"$@"` will expand to each individual command line argument, quoted, which gives you a test that essentially looks like `[ -z "f132a99" "f132a98" "f132a97" ]` for three arguments.

What you should do, if you want the user to only ever give a single argument, is exactly what you mention [in your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/579324/116858), i.e. use a test like `[ "$#" -ne 1 ]` to test for invalid input.

However, there is another option, and that is to consider *all* of the given arguments as user IDs, and loop over them:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'No user ID given' >&2
    exit 1
fi

for userid do
    # code to process "$userid" goes here
done
```

---

Other notes about your code:

The test for valid user IDs is flawed.  Consider a system where there is no user called `bill`, but where there *is* a `billy`.  Entering `bill` as the user ID would not detect this as an invalid user ID with `grep -q "$userid" /etc/passwd` (this command would possibly also generate an error if the `$userid` string started with a dash).

It would be better to test with `getent -- passwd "$userid"`, and to perform all operations related to getting data out of the `passwd` database through `getent passwd`.

You have a similar issue with `who | grep "$userid"`, which is better written as `who | grep -q "^$userid\>"`.

I mentioned these things [in my answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579032/if-statements-with-exit-code-statements/579280#579280).

Comment: `grep -q "^$userid\>"` would still find `bill` in `bill.gates`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo -n "Please enter a single, valid user id: "
    read userid
else
    userid="$1"
fi
```